# How to navigate to different components in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to make reusable buttons Left arrow and Right arrow, on clicking them I can navigate to different components/pages. I am making a calendar, I want to achieve, on pressing these arrow buttons I can navigate to different months.
I can do this using `<Link to="/path">` `Link` tag on every component, but this will be violation of ***Don't Repeat Yourself*** principle. Is there any way to achieve this functionality by making reusable button, where I don't have to pass `<Link to="/path">` in every component?

These are routes on App.jsx

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
  <Route exact path='/home' element={<HomePage />} />
  <Route path='nov2023' element={<SinglePage title='November 2023' />} />
  <Route path='dec2023' element={<SinglePage title='December 2023' />} />
  <Route path='jan' element={<SinglePage title='January 2024' />} />
  <Route path='feb' element={<SinglePage title='Febuary 2024' />} />
  <Route path='mar' element={<SinglePage title='March 2024' />} />
  <Route path='apr' element={<SinglePage title='April 2024' />} />
  <Route path='may' element={<SinglePage title='May 2024' />} />
  <Route path='jun' element={<SinglePage title='June 2024' />} />
  <Route path='jul' element={<SinglePage title='July 2024' />} />
  <Route path='aug' element={<SinglePage title='August 2024' />} />
  <Route path='sep' element={<SinglePage title='September 2024' />} />
  <Route path='oct' element={<SinglePage title='October 2024' />} />
  <Route path='nov' element={<SinglePage title='November 2024' />} />
  <Route path='dec' element={<SinglePage title='December 2024' />} />
  <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />} />
</Routes>
```

```
import { useNavigate, useNavigation } from "react-router-dom";

const SinglePage = ({ title }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div className='h-screen px-2 bg-cyan-200'>
      <div className='flex flex-col items-center pt-20 space-y-5 text-center space-between'>
        <Logo />
        <MonthTitle title={title} />
        <SootheSensesPara />
      </div>
      <div className='flex justify-end space-x-2 items-center sm:px-[50px] md:px-[100px]'>
        <p onClick={() => navigation(-1)} className='flex-0'>
          **LA**
        </p>
        <div className='flex-1'>
          <BirdCard />
        </div>
        <p onClick={() => navigation(+1)} className='flex-0'>
          **RA**
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SinglePage;
```

```
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div className='bg-green-100 px-10 sm:px-[50px] md:px-[100px]'>
      <div className='pt-20 space-y-5 text-center '>
        <LogoSafex />
        <SootheSensesPara />
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-5 '>
        <CalenderCard month='November' path='/nov2023' />
        <CalenderCard month='December' path='/dec2023' />
        <CalenderCard month='January' path='/jan' />
        <CalenderCard month='Febuary' path='/feb' />
        <CalenderCard month='March' path='/mar' />
        <CalenderCard month='April' path='/apr' />
        <CalenderCard month='May' path='/may' />
        <CalenderCard month='June' path='/jun' />
        <CalenderCard month='July' path='/jul' />
        <CalenderCard month='August' path='/aug' />
        <CalenderCard month='September' path='/sep' />
        <CalenderCard month='October' path='/oct' />
        <CalenderCard month='November' path='/nov' />
        <CalenderCard month='December' path='/dec' />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

On clicking LA and RA I want to navigate to previous and next component/page, i.e. on click RA from November 2023 to December 2023

Comment: Are you trying to navigate forward/backward through the history stack? That should work as-is with the `navigate(-1|1)` code that is already there. Or are you trying to programmatically navigate? Can you [edit] to clarify better what exactly the issue is? Can you clarify what links you are referring to, and what they are linking to, specifically?

Comment: useHistory() is deprecated in react-router v6, so i'm trying to navigate programmatically or any other way in which I don't have to hard code path in every page

Comment: Is that even relevant? It was replaced by the `useNavigate` hook which your code is clearly using.

Comment: If you did hard code the path on every page... what would you hard code? In other words.... what is meant by "next" and "previous" here? If you mean user is on `"/mar"` and you want next to be `"/apr"` and previous to be `"/feb"`, well, you'll need to code that logic/behavior/mapping *somewhere*. The app needs to know where it is ***now*** to know what is "next" or "previous". Does this make sense?

Comment: I would use 
for Ex -> on December 2023
<Link path = "/nov2023">Left Arrow</Link>
<Link path = "/jan">Right Arrow</Link>

Comment: Yeah, got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to load up all the month data into an array that can be searched.

```js
const months = [
  {
    id: "nov2023",
    month: "November",
    path: "/nov2023",
    title: "November 2023"
  },
  {
    id: "dec2023",
    month: "December",
    path: "/dec2023",
    title: "December 2023"
  },
  ....
  {
    id: "nov",
    month: "November",
    path: "/nov",
    title: "November 2024"
  },
  {
    id: "dec",
    month: "December",
    path: "/dec",
    title: "December 2024"
  }
];
```

This array will be used to map to `CalendarCard` components in the `HomePage` ***and*** as a lookup utility function to compute the current, and next and previous month data.

```
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-green-100 px-10 sm:px-[50px] md:px-[100px]">
      <div className="pt-20 space-y-5 text-center ">
        <LogoSafex />
        <SootheSensesPara />
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-5 ">
        {months.map((month) => (
          <CalenderCard month={month} key={month.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const getMonthData = (current) => {
  const index = months.findIndex((month) => month.id === current);

  return {
    current: months[index],
    previous: months[index - 1],
    next: months[index + 1]
  };
};
```

The `SinglePage` component will read a new `month` route path parameter and compute the `current`, `next`, and `previous`

```
const SinglePage = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigate();
  const { month } = useParams();

  const { current, next, previous } = getMonthData(month);

  return (
    <div className="h-screen px-2 bg-cyan-200">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center pt-20 space-y-5 text-center space-between">
        <Logo />
        <MonthTitle title={current?.title} />
        <SootheSensesPara />
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-end space-x-2 items-center sm:px-[50px] md:px-[100px]">
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => navigation(previous?.path)}
          className="flex-0"
        >
          {"<<"}
        </button>
        <div className="flex-1">
          <BirdCard />
        </div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => navigation(next?.path)}
          className="flex-0"
        >
          {">>"}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
  <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
  <Route path="/:month" element={<SinglePage />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
</Routes>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit how-to-navigate-to-different-components-in-react-js]